# images.get_serving_url(blob_key) returns error when ran from appengine in cloud.

Tags: google-app-engine

images.get_serving_url() returns the below error when ran from appengine in cloud but work fine when run in local environment. It works for fine image files saved in blob store, the issue is only with vido files. I am stuck with this and I dont know how to debug this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

File "/base/data/home/apps/s~silicon-window-102123/1.387642514189268755/main.py", line 95, in post
    url=images.get_serving_url(localkey)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/images/**init**.py", line 1794, in get_serving_url
    return rpc.get_result()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 613, in get_result
    return self.**get_result_hook(self)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/images/__init**.py", line 1892, in get_serving_url_hook
    raise _ToImagesError(e, readable_blob_key)
TransformationError

Answer (score 1):

The clue is in the error thrown: `TransformationError`

It does not work for video files. In the documentation for [get_serving_url](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/refdocs/google.appengine.api.images)

> google.appengine.api.images.get_serving_url(blob_key, size=None,
>   crop=False, secure_url=None, filename=None, rpc=None)[source]

the method is described as '*Obtain a url that will serve the underlying **image***'.

And some of the options don't make all that much sense for video. The word video does not appear on that page. It's not supported.

Comment: yeah I thought the same, but when it worked in my local environment I assumed it would work on the cloud and went continued the dev. Now I have hit a wall.

Comment: Out of interest, in what sense does it "work"? What's the kind of URL that you get back?

Comment: I get this URL="http://127.0.0.1:8080/_ah/img/3vLur65v3fO8mvMM1HXx8A==" and video plays fine, but the same code throws error on cloud